# Power supply choke for amplifier

Tags: power-supply, amplifier

I made a symmetrical power supply:

[image]

But when I connected it to my amplifier I heard a hum in a speaker, and let's say that my amplifier is working fine and the problem is not in it. I know that a coil increases its resistance with increasing frequency so it blocks high frequency. And if I know right, this high frequency is not good for amplifier. Can I use a choke to reduce this hum?

[image]

If yes, should it be connected to a primary winding or secondary windings of the transformer connected to my supply?

Comment: What frequency is the hum?

Comment: Can you show how the 4 terminals X3-1, etc, are connected to mains voltage?   Also are these two identical transformers or a single transformer with a centre tap?

Comment: "*let's say that my amplifier is working fine and the problem is not in it*" -- that's a big assumption, though, and if the circuit is indeed as shown, I would be inclined to suspect the amplifier is in fact the problem. I would want to see proof of this circuit not working correctly, first (scope readings? capacitor tests?). Basically, an amplifier should have enough PSRR not to be bothered by this circuit. Or the component values/ratings are unsuited to the load (too small C for load current), which is also important information.

Comment: So you don't think this filter would help ?